# you have specified an invalid column ordinal in mysql Using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have tried this code to show data from MySQL database using C# in some labels but it keeps tell me that i have specified an invalid column ordinal

```
 private void store_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root";
                    string Query = "select Value from birth.store;";
                    MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection(constring);
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, c);
                    MySqlDataReader reader;
                    try
                    {
                        c.Open();
                        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                            label3.Text = reader.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                            label4.Text = reader.GetInt64(0).ToString();
                            label6.Text = reader.GetInt64(8).ToString();
                            label10.Text = reader.GetInt64(5).ToString();
                            label14.Text = reader.GetInt64(7).ToString();
                            label13.Text = reader.GetInt64(13).ToString();
                            label11.Text = reader.GetInt64(10).ToString();
                            label20.Text = reader.GetInt64(12).ToString();
                            label19.Text = reader.GetInt64(16).ToString();
                            label17.Text = reader.GetInt64(14).ToString();
                            label26.Text = reader.GetInt64(15).ToString();
                            label32.Text = reader.GetInt64(4).ToString();
                            label31.Text = reader.GetInt64(6).ToString();
                            label23.Text = reader.GetInt64(3).ToString();
                            label27.Text = reader.GetInt64(2).ToString();
                            label25.Text = reader.GetInt64(11).ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: @GrantWinney so what sould i do

Comment: @GrantWinney i wanna to display in every label the value of a specific cell of one column to i tried this code

Comment: @GrantWinney do you have another code to do that instat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a number to `GetInt32()` that is too large for the number of columns in your query. The index that you pass to `reader.GetInt32()` or `reader.GetInt64()` is the position of that column in your SELECT statement in your query, starting with 0. Your query looks like this:

```
string Query = "select Value from birth.store;";
```

There is only one column (the names between `SELECT` and `FROM`), so any number higher than 0 is invalid if passed to reader.GetInt32(). The more columns you have in your query, the higher the number you can pass.

**Example with 1 column:**

```
string Query = "select Value from birth.store;";
// database connection and reader execution go here
string Value = reader.GetInt32(0).toString(); // This gets the column Value
```

**Example with 3 column:**

```
// We're selecting 3 columns now
// 0 = Id
// 1 = Value
// 2 = Name
string Query = "select Id, Value, Name from birth.store;";
// database connection and reader execution go here

string Value = reader.GetInt32(1).toString(); // This gets the column Value

// This gets the column Id. Even though it's not the first one we pulled from
// the reader, it's still #0 on the list of 3 columns.
string Id = reader.GetInt32(0).toString(); 
string Name = reader.GetInt32(2).toString(); // This gets the column Name

// This will throw an exception. You're trying to get the 4th item on a list
// that starts with 0, but there are only 3 items (numbered 0, 1, 2).
string AnotherValue = reader.GetInt32(3).toString();
```